# Alter Views query limit using views_query_alter

Tags: views

I want to alter the limit of view using `views_query_alter` hook.

My code is :

```
function track_click_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if($view->name == "click_list_days"){
  $w_count = count($query->where[0]['clauses']) - 1;
  $w_clause = array();
  for($i=0; $i <= $w_count; $i++) {
      $w_clause[] = "(".$query->where[0]['clauses'][$i].")";
      if($i > 0)
          unset ($query->where[0]['clauses'][$i]);
  }
  $w_clause = implode(" AND ", $w_clause)." Group By track_click.article_title ";
  $query->where[0]['clauses'][0] = $w_clause;
  }
}
```

How can I alter the limit of this views query? I didn't understand which query object i have to alter.

Comment: "which query object"? But there is only one, `&$query`. I don't understand what you don't know.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i mean, object `$query->where` contains the conditions added in views settings. Like that `$query->limit` variable is available for alter query limit? or else where i can alter the query limit in `views_query_alter`?

Comment: It is usually safer to use API methods instead of changing the objects data structure directly. You can have a look at `views/plugins/views_plugin_query.inc` to see which methods are available.

Comment: It works for my custom rest api views pager
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185977/alter-views-limit-using-hook-views-query-alter/232484#232484#answer-232484

Answer (score 3):

If it's only about the number of results to return, I think you could simply implement [hook_views_pre_build()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/7) and do the following:

```
function track_click_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'click_list_days') {
    $view->set_items_per_page(YOUR_NUMBER_OF_RESULTS_HERE);
  }
}
```

Or inside `hook_views_query_alter()` you should be able to do:

```
$query->set_limit(LIMIT);
```

Comment: is it not possible to do with `views_query_alter`? because some code is already written to alter the query based on some condition in `views_query_alter`. So I want to add the limit with that condition.

Comment: I added yoiur code in views_query_alter `$view->set_items_per_page(YOUR_NUMBER_OF_RESULTS_HERE); 
I think it is working. Let me confirm.

Comment: @ARUN: Yes, you should be able to do this inside `hook_views_query_alter()` too. I have updated the response accordingly.

Comment: `$query->set_limit(LIMIT);` inside `hook_views_query_alter()` is not working. But `$view->set_items_per_page(YOUR_NUMBER_OF_RESULTS_HERE);` is working iniside `hook_views_query_alter()`

Comment: $query->set_limit() is not working in hook_views_query_alter(). Is any other solutions?