# Alter views limit using hook_views_query_alter

Tags: views

I've used **display specified number of items** for set limit in views.
I want to change limit and also display all items using hook_views_query_alter().
I've tried this:

```
function test_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'sample') {
    $query->set_limit(20);
    //~ $view->set_items_per_page(20);
  }
}
```

But i've no luck. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) { 
    $view->set_items_per_page(2);     
}
```

Comment: I got this error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method view::set_use_pager() "

Comment: Please remove set_use_page line. Pager should work with set_items_per_page only.

Comment: It is working fine for alter limit only. If i want to remove pager, then how can do that?

Comment: I get the same error. I guess this answer if for Drupal 7 though. For Drupal 8, using $view->getPager()->setItemsPerPage($nb); as said in another answer works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal 8.

I created views in rest mode for send 10 items per page. But the native pager was not works for me.
So, I implemented **hook_views_query_alter**() for set up custom pager settings with limit and offset.

1) Create **custom_rest_api.views_executable.inc** file for implement the hook

2) Set views offset and page limit

```
/**
 * @file
 * Containts custom_rest_api.views_executable.inc.
 */

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function custom_rest_api_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view,     QueryPluginBase $query) {
   if ($view->id() == "news" && !empty($view->args)) {
   $number = (int) ($view->args[0]);
   $number--;

   $limit = 10;
   $offset = $limit * $number;

   $view->setOffset($offset);
   $view->getPager()->setItemsPerPage($limit);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Took me some time to remember $view->getPager()->setItemsPerPage($limit); is only working when pager option is set to **'Display a specified number of items'**